# Should stackoverflow.com have rounded corners?

Tags: feature-request, design

I noticed that [doctype](http://doctype.com/) has rounded corners on its profiles and buttons. A website without rounded corners in 2010 is like site from 1999 without a frameset (and possibly invalid html)

Can we have some:

```
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│-moz-border-radius-topleft / -webkit-border-top-left-radius         │
│-moz-border-radius-topright / -webkit-border-top-right-radius       │
│-moz-border-radius-bottomleft / -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius   │
│-moz-border-radius-bottomright / -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Comment: Don't let anyone know what browser you use.

Comment: For the record, my vote is in for a flash splash page on SO.

Comment: If it was added, Internet Explorer users shouldn't get it as a punishment for using IE

Comment: The comparison with frames is fairly apt: Note how history has decided that frames were, in fact, a bad idea.

Comment: The top 3 supermarkets in the UK still use framesets

Comment: Sorry, but having square corners in your code sample is unacceptable, please make them round. And don't give me any "But that's not possible" answer, even the C64 could do rounded corners in Text.

Comment: I knew there was a ╭ somewhere but couldn't find it. Brings back memories of making msdos menus

Comment: What good are rounded corners if you don't have a guest book and a visitor counter?

Comment: @apaul34208, are you sure your fonts are okay? The revision before your edit looked fine in Chrome and Firefox on my Mac; alexy's fix also aligns fine, though the two new characters are slightly different. alexy, I guess you just typed a dash rather than copy & paste a horizontal line from the existing Markdown source to duplicate it? Your two characters [look slightly thinner to me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OhJM9.png).

Comment: @Arjan looks off to me in both Firefox and Chrome on windows7

Comment: @Arjan when I edited I just added spaces to line it up, fonts are fine using default settings

Comment: Yeah, @apaul34208, these Unicode tables [are known to cause problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables/139013#139013). If I paste your Markdown version into a text editor, I see lines of 74 and 75 columns. Also, if I [edit your version in the Markdown editor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/35052/edit/f4d1bcb5-89b7-48b3-bd38-4b5871b31487) then I see different line lengths, and moving the cursor from the end of the first line to the next, makes the cursor end up *before* the last character on the lines you changed...?

Comment: @Arjan It doesn't really look like this question is going to go anywhere, I wouldn't worry about it too much

Comment: By far the funniest question I have ever seen in SE. Good job!

Comment: Sure, @apaul34208, but I'm only referring to the edit... Don't you see the different line lengths after your edit?

Comment: @Arjan What do you mean by different line lengths? This is what I see now: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4oEmj.png When I edited I just lined up the right side. At least it looked lined up on my PC.

Comment: @apaul34208, while editing [your version](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/35052/edit/f4d1bcb5-89b7-48b3-bd38-4b5871b31487), the first and last lines of the box seem to be 73 characters, while the others are 74 characters. (Also easily shown [in a text editor](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MHoEM.png).) Also, if I put my cursor *after* the last character of the first line line, and then use the arrow keys to go down one line, I see the cursor *before* the last character of that second line. If you get the same, then beware when trusting the displaying of Unicode box drawing on your computer.

Comment: I'm quite sure my fonts are okay (referring to the edit)--it appears that the horizontal line that I used was a dash instead of copy and pasting. I'll try copy and pasting and see what I get. I didn't use markdown and therefore, I don't have the source :(. I do agree though that my line is slightly thinner--before it was very obvious, now it's a little less obvious.

Comment: I just fixed that odd line thing, and I'll wait for a mod to accept it (hopefully!). Thank you @Arjan for pointing that out!

Answer (score 71):

Why stop there?

[image]

Comment: Needs more epilepsy inducing banners.

Comment: Needs blue lens flare.

Comment: Needs to be in perspective / 3D, maybe with each question text on an animated flag waving in the wind? All done in jQuery, of course ;-p

Comment: The questions as a rolodex/carousel

Comment: Mmm, I made my own one: http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/3787/lolzg.png | Source code: http://pastebin.com/f775bdad

Comment: You could round the avatars/user pictures too. ...although on second thought, I like the look of those tags.

Comment: Cover-.. eh, Question-flow!

Comment: I kinda like this...Am I the only one that does?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I certainly hope so

Comment: Now add one of these to it: http://www.mywebpresenters.com/ and it's perfect

Comment: Needs more cowbell.

Comment: Why no background image?  I think you're selling it short.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: No, you are not the only one... I think that it is beautiful, although I would make the mirrored effect less pronounced, and lose the shadows on the question titles, and make the tabs look more "traditional", that is round the bottoms outwards, not inwards. I realise that this is meant to be a joke, but it does look pretty slick, without over complicating the page.

Comment: -1, not enough bevel.

Comment: Yes, bevel and Comic Sans.

Comment: More cowbell, please.

Comment: OMG so shiny. :D

Comment: Would't want someone to poked on those sharp edges!

Comment: Some of it is over the top (as per your point) but I like some of it. The mirrors on the nav links and logo are pretty good, updates the website a bit. Although shadows on 'all' text, meh, *shudders*. Especially with the blue text colour. Looks like a cheesy 90's site logo made by a back street car garage company owner on MS Word..

Comment: Open SO and write the following in the URL, and you immediate take SO back to the future: `javascript:R=0; x1=.1; y1=.05; x2=.25; y2=.24; x3=1.6; y3=.24; x4=300; y4=200; x5=300; y5=200; var DI= document.getElementsByClassName("question-summary"); DIL=DI.length; function A(){for(i=0; i<DIL; i++){DIS=DI[ i ].style; DIS.position='absolute'; DIS.left=Math.sin(R*x1+i*x2+x3)*x4+x5+"px"; DIS.top=Math.cos(R*y1+i*y2+y3)*y4+y5+"px"}R++}tag=setInterval('A()',5 );document.onmousedown=function(){clearInterval(tag);for(i=0; i<DIL; i++){DI[i].style.position="static";}}; void(0)`

Comment: Slow day at work?

Comment: @Johnny I didn't even work at Stack Overflow yet when I made this. Look at the answer date.

Comment: @balpha - I didn't even know you worked there now!

Comment: Eeek! My eyes!!!!

Answer (score 15):

Doctype has a border? Really?

Honestly, I don't much notice all the fancy shmancy mark-up frills. Instead, I read the *text* of the pages. I'm a programmer, so obviously *function* is more important to me than *form*. As long as it looks fairly reasonable (e.g., no wild color combinations or distracting animated widgets), I don't much care about minor things like rounded corners and alpha transparencies.

You can spend hours of wasted time twiddling with things like that (I know I have for certain inflexible managers). But at some point you have to realize you're just adding more lipstick to the pig.

Comment: Did you call Stack Overflow a pig?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar, Umm...

Answer (score 5):

You mean rounded corners like this? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges

Comment: The aliasing on those corners are... for the lack of a more polite word, very ugly ^^ Superuser has that same problem for tags...

Comment: @Oskar thats the way the browser implements it, note how badges have square corners in ie. To get silky smooth corners you use sliding doors or some other css png transparency trick, the trouble is that theming something becomes more of an annoyance

Answer (score 4):

Rounded corners are so late 2000, flat design with square boxes (á la "the-ui-formerly-known-as-metro" style) is the new shiny thing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get it, everything is square to me.

Oh wait, IE8.

Seriously, rounded corners are overused and usually aren't that great either - they do have their places and uses but in general they don't fit that well into website flow that there'd be reason to have them everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Square corners are not merely a lack of a rounded corners feature. They are a valid aesthetic choice in and of themselves.

I personally would be put off by the excessive beveling and texturing that is becoming ubiquitous in user interfaces now, and prefer the current design, which focuses on typography and organisation rather than skeumorphism.

Comment: I agree that "it's fine", but beveling, texturing, effects ect. are becoming less and less popular. Take a look at IOS 7 and Windows 8 and compare them to their respective previous versions. They rely on typography and organization as well.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow.com is not "pomp and circumstance".  It's the premiere site to go for answers to your tech questions (or tech questions within established guidelines).  There are so many bugs and other issues, and a GAWD-AWFUL huge queue of reviews, that I think the designers efforts are best suited to other tasks.  SO is not so out-of-date that it's a huge issue.  Look at Google.  There's plenty of non-rounded stuff there, and I don't think they're in any current danger of being irrelevant.