# Warn user when their code is larger than 80 characters

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, code-block, warning

Scrolling horizontally is hard. Warning someone that posts code that is larger than 80 characters against the readability problem this causes would be a solution to avoid then from the start.

Comment: We already have a question preview area that shows things fairly faithfully. What kind of additional warning are you proposing?

Comment: Having trouble in your CRT terminal?

Comment: -1, 80 is maximum including tab 4 character in linux kernel development. so that per line you read less (put more attention, what u just readed) but vertically read more.

Comment: @PopularDemand : a non modal message, something that warns, or at least, notices.

Comment: @Marcelo: "lol"

Comment: @PopularDemand: One could also imagine a two-limit system, like phpcodesniffer does : 80 characters => notice; 150 characters => warning

Comment: I'd rather see some way to open a code block in some much wider popup. (Or maybe some [copy code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow) option.) But I agree: on systems that do not show scrollbars unless one *is* scrolling (like mobile devices,  or like OS X Lion's default settings) I dislike scrolling code even more.

Comment: @Arjan: that's also a good solution, but it's something that could be done too, not instead of.

Comment: @Google: You downvote me, and then you say something that seems to argue in favor of what I'm saying (though I'm not sure I understand what you put between brackets)

Answer (score 4):

The number of characters at which horizontal scroll bars are produced is not universal.  See:

[What is the average number of characters in a Code block before scroll bars appear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82180/average-number-of-characters-in-a-code-block-before-scroll-bars)

Since I asked that question I am using a different system, and now the max char width does not change with zoom, but it is still nonstandard (currently 87 characters).

Comment: And on the mobile theme, things are [even *more* different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables/73567#73567).

Comment: Still, I think there should be a limit, and the norm seems to be 80 characters.

Answer (score -1):

### Ow Ow Ow.

I have a cramp from scrolling horizontally....

Yes I am being facetious.

How is it so hard to scroll horizontally?

If the code is that long, that is what will happen, I see no reason to discourage it unless it makes it so that you cannot read the code.

#### AHHH

But if you take that above sentence and put it like this:

```
 If the code is that long, that is what will happen, I see no reason to discourage it unless it makes it so that you cannot read the code.
```

**YES** it is very uneasy to read.

In that situation I would discourage the post, but how is the system to know the difference between that and:

```
  function areallyreallylongfunctionnamethattakesupawholelinewhichisbadpracticebutitistheopscode(){
      .....
  }
```

Comment: Well, if it's just a warning, the system doesn't have to distinguish between them.

Comment: If you have such method names, then you have a problem: perhaps your class has too much methods in it.

Comment: Note that some systems only show scrollbars while actually scrolling. Like when using Mac OS X Lion's default settings, one has [no real indication](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VllMG.png) that something is scrollable. (Apart from the text being cut off, if applicable. On Macs I use, I set the scrollbars [to be always visible](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IZmAK.png).) Also some tablets behave like that, though the mobile theme tries to outsmart those [by wrapping code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables/73567#73567).