# Horizontal scroll bar appears in Google Chrome when not needed (line with 93 characters with default zoom)

Tags: bug, google-chrome, code-block

The horizontal scroll bar appears in Google Chrome (with default zoom) when a line  93 has characters, which isn't needed. Example:

```
model_saver.save(sess, os.path.join(model_folder, 'model_{0:05d}.ckpt'.format(epoch_number)))
```

Rendering:

[image]

It works fine with firefox:

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason that we should expect to get a full 93 characters? Does it matter?

Comment: @Catija To make use the entire width.

Comment: I still don't see why it matters.... the "full width" of 93 characters is just happenstance in how the site was designed, right?

Comment: @Catija That is correct, 93 was a decision from Stack Exchange. Some users format their posts based on Stack Exchange design choices.

Comment: Your post looks like this to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r6Gq.png (chrome on linux, default zoom). Seems like it's well over what can fit without a scroll bar. I do see something similar if I chop it down to 84 characters. So, yeah, the bug's still there - but if you're using 93 characters hoping to be friendly, it's not working anyway.

Comment: I am kind of curious where you learned about this as a decision - it sounds like you mean it's something more than just testing out what the limit is on your own computer, but all I could find was an old meta post suggesting it was 81 characters for most people: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82182/133299

Comment: 93 characters is one more than what I can see under Chrome.

Comment: @Jefromi Thanks, interesting, I didn't expect that much variance across browsers and operating systems. I have used Chrome and firefox on Microsoft Windows 7, as far as I can recall the limit has always been 93.