# Table in Answers & Questions

Tags: support, markdown, tables

I want to use a table in my answer.

e.g

|-------------|----------------|
| ShortCut    | Description    |
|-------------|----------------|

I have posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410191/hidden-features-of-xcode-4/6544639#6544639), which requires this kind of formatting.

Is it possible to have such formatting in stackoverflow Questions & answers ?

- If yes, How ?
- If no, why ?

Edit : I tried to use following code directly in editor of SO. But it didn't work for me.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>hello3</td>
<td>hello4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer is here:  http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/is-there-a-webapp-to-create-ascii-art-tables  first answer links to a website that will do this for you.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question. This question is about tables -- that question is about *ASCII* tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Standard Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) should have allowed in-lined HTML table. However, seems it's not supported by SE's implementation of Markdown.

There are currently few Markdown implementation, which do support [tables syntax](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table) originally created for PHP Markdown Extra.

Tables in above syntax have source like this:

```
| Left align | Right align | Center align |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| This       |        This |     This     |
| column     |      column |    column    |
| will       |        will |     will     |
| be         |          be |      be      |
| left       |       right |    center    |
| aligned    |     aligned |   aligned    |
```

And are rendered as HTML table, which looks like this:

[image: rendered table]

Example table is from [this Python implementation.](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2008/08/tables-for-markdown-and-textmate/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Unicode characters. For example:

```
                   [My DataTabel]                                     
  ┌───────────┬───────────┼───────────┬───────────┐
  │  Field#1  │  Field#2  │    ∙∙∙    │  Field#n  │
  ├───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
  │ Data[1-1] │ Data[1-2] │    ∙∙∙    │ Data[1-n] │
  ├───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
  │ Data[2-1] │ Data[2-2] │    ∙∙∙    │ Data[2-n] │
  ├───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
  │    ∙∙∙    │    ∙∙∙    │    ∙∙∙    │    ∙∙∙    │
  ├───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤ 
  │ Data[m-1] │ Data[m-2] │    ∙∙∙    │ Data[m-n] │ 
  └───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Those are box-drawing characters, not 7-bit ASCII characters.

Comment: updated to unicode

Answer (score 3):

I fail to see why a table is needed for that answer.

But if you want to create a table, your best bet is to use the one you've posted in code tags:

```
|-------------|----------------|
| ShortCut    | Description    |
|-------------|----------------|
```

This could also be extended with Unicode.

It does not support extended formatting, though.

Comment: does <code> tag supports <kbd> tag within it ?

Comment: @sugar: No, I don't think so.

Comment: I posted the link to my answer just because I want to give some Idea of a case where Table is very necessary to demonstrate neat & sharp.

Comment: Note that the mobile theme uses wrapping, not scrolling. Makes ASCII tables [look very bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables/73567#73567).