# HTML table in question or answer? Other way to format spreadsheet style data?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hidden-features

I had a question on a stack exchange site (see link below) that got me wondering the best way to format data that was part of my question.

It's basically a spreadsheet.  I tried uploading as tab delimited, and raw html but neither seemed to work very well.  SO I finally uploaded as html in a code window for the end user to use.

Is there a better way to put row/column data in a question or answer on so?

[SQL Disk Setup Advice - TempDB, Log DB, Data file placement question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5485/sql-disk-setup-advice-tempdb-log-db-data-file-placement-question)

Comment: Related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables