# How to insert tables in the answer block?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)

How to insert tables into the text area.For now i am pasting images instead of tables. Why is it not allowed to insert tables?