# How to draw an HTML table while posting in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)

Could someone please give me an example for creating a multi-row table while posting questions in SO. I found the example given in The MarkDown documentation unsatisfactory. When I am trying to create a table, a new tr tag does not lead to a line break and placing contents on next line and I can see no cells being created.