# Reputation 10 to post images

Tags: support, privileges, images

I have previously tried asking questions as simply as possible but they have been blocked like in the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025883/rdlc-report-matrix-sum-of-averages-of-subtotal

So owning up to my mistake I tried posting a detailed question but table tags are not available in here to format my sample dat ; so I went for images and alas it tells me that I need atleast a reputation of 10 to post images!

Please somebody help me to post my question.

Comment: If you just add a link to the image in your question, people will usually edit your question for you and replace the link with the image.

Comment: Improve your closed question by editing it. Host the images elsewhere (e.g. on http://imgur.com) and other users will embed it into your post shortly. When done post comment to the moderator by `@Brad please reopen, I improved the question` and he might reopen the question. (You can't flag just yet)

Comment: Good migration, SO

Answer (score 10):

Very new accounts have some strict restrictions to defend against spambots.

However, a very few upvotes that you receive by asking [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions (or providing solutions to questions) will get you through such restrictions in no time.

---

For the very specific case of needing to post an image with < 10 rep, upload it to some hosting service such as [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and link to it -- odds are a 2k+ rep user will promptly [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) the question adding the image to it, as long as your question and image are on-topic.

---

As for tabular data, the matter is bit more [tricky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables). The consensus is to drawn a code-formatted - or better, put it inside a `<pre>` tag to don't trigger syntax highlighting, as commented by @ScottChamberlain - ASCII table to get a quick and dirty tabular data representation done.

Images are appropriate as well and often can represent tabular data better, though these are technically shorter-lived. Also, ensure that your question holds meaning without relying on external resources, so that the question does not get [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) as Too Localized.

---

And about the question ban, see the canonical topic: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: When doing ASCII tables the `<pre></pre>` tags are very useful, they do the code formatting but do not do any of the code highlighting/coloring. Create the table in a program that does not word-wrap and then copy and paste the text with the tags above and below it and it should look the same as the original text (if your editor uses a mono-spaced font)

Comment: That's a nice tip, so far I've used the 4 spaces indentation with the `<!-- language: lang-none -->` comment above, but `<pre>` tags are way less conturbed. `=]`

Comment: lol, and I never knew about the Language flag, can you point me to a link where I can find out more info about it? that is a feature I will definatly start using.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/186879

Comment: Another useful thing, [this site](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) was created by a [Stack Exchange user](http://superuser.com/users/14797/senseful), specifically to make putting tables in to a question or answer easier.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Woah, did not know nor expect that. Handy tool. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

Ten reputation.  That's...

- two upvotes on a question.  So roughly, one good question, or two just okay questions.
- Five suggested edits approved.
- One upvoted answer.
- One accepted answer.
- One upvote on a question and 2 suggested edits approved.

All you have to do is [ask a good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get this privilege.  The question you linked is one that we regard as a poor question, however.  Please read through the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page and the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), which you were linked to before you posted your first question, to learn how to do this better.

Comment: (Note: I think that now upvoted questions are worth the same as upvoted answers, so only one question upvote would be needed to get 10 rep.)