# My inputed text becomes a scramble

Tags: support, markdown

This is the formatting I want. I enter text in this way
[image: formatting I want]

but it shows in this way
[image: formatting I don't want]

The first line of my text was indented in four spaces, so it was show as a line of code, how to set it to normal text? And the spaces between numbers are collapsed, how to solve it?

Comment: Related:- http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/221351

Comment: You have to give four space on both title and records. Otherwise it will skip multiple space.

Answer (score 2):

Just indent all of the lines 4 spaces or more:

```
   foo     bar
1    2       3
5    6       2
```

Comment: Off-topic is not correct here @EdCottrell. Such support questions are perfectly on-topic for Meta. Duplicate, possibly. And there is formatting help out there. But not off-topic.

Comment: @Bart Okay; I'm still getting the hang of Meta. I edited my answer.