# Why can't we use `table` markup in answers?

Tags: discussion, markdown, tables

This question has been asked before and marked a [duplicate of this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables).

Alas, that question's answers merely point out that we can't use tables in answers.

Is there a reason why this is a feature that's never been implemented (as you can see there are a lot of questions on this topic in Meta).

I see a few strong arguments for considering it:

- it's useful. Today I wanted to format a building code load table as a (obviously!) table! But then learned that's not something we can do with markdown or the allowed HTML tags.
- we can use `pre` which works. Sort of. The problems with this, though, are that a) we lose all the important accessibility features that proper table markup provides. b) `pre` text on mobile is kind of a pain.

Maybe there's a good reason why this isn't a feature offered. Maybe it's a bad reason. Either way, I was just curious as to whether or not there was a reason and what that might be.

Answer (score 5):

Actually yes, it [does explain why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228464/263510), mostly by linking to [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/934/please-can-we-have-markdown-tables-on-dba-se/966#966).

To paraphrase the paraphrasing there, it's just that it would mess up a ton of stuff on the page, layout-wise. Imagine a table that was wider than the allowable input (since tables allow you to force width relatively easily). The best alternative would be to throw everything in an `iframe`, but that wouldn't make for a very nice UI in every other case.

Comment: Couldn't it just be scrolled?

Comment: I don't understand that reasoning, but that is an explanation! Thanks!