# Is support for Markdown tables on Stack Overflow planned?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, markdown-rendering, tables

I've found a [question about tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables) asking if they are supported, and answers saying that it isn't, but there are suggestions about several different hacks. And even though the question is relatively old, it seems to still hold true.

But I'm wondering if this functionality is planned for any time soon?

And is there an actual reason they didn't want to support tables?

Comment: Well actually @random, my question is the exact opposite of that. He explicitly said he doesn't care about the "why", while I explicitly wanted to know the "why". the closest answer to my question is this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/345373. However, it still doesn't say why. If there is some security risk with tables in markdown, I would also like to know what it is, so that I stop using them too.

Comment: Both ask for Markdown tables. That's the actual feature request. If you want to lump another question in there that's whatever, but that doesn't change the inherent request

Comment: @random Then what and where should I ask to find out **why** tables were omitted in the first place, without implying it's a request? I'm just very curious, and it seems like some top secret, nobody says why.

Comment: Because tables will screw up the overall page layout and when loaded they will cause render delays client side are a couple of reasons that spring to mind.

Comment: The reason is right in the link you said you've read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables/228464#228464

Comment: Post layouts use html tables, so they're probably waiting until they refactor this prior to bringing in html tables (they already support it, see Documentation).  A good estimate of how long this will take is approximately [6 to 8 weeks.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)