# Label a matrix with a number in markdown language

Tags: support, markdown

I want this in the Markdown language.

[image]

I try the following code (that works for LaTeX):

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 
  \end{bmatrix}
  \label{eq:aeqn}
\end{equation}
```

But it's not working for the Markdown language. It only create the matrix, but it does not label a number.

Comment: That's not markdown - it is Tex/MathJax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables)

Comment: @MCCCS it might look like a table but it definitely is not and the current answer can't go on that dupe so I don't think that duplicate is correct.

Comment: So to be clear, you're saying you're *using* that code on one of our Stacks that support MathJax, and the matrix is rendering correctly, but its label isn't showing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do that on a site that has Mathjax enabled.

You might be able to fake it up by using code formatting.

```
|1   2|                            (1)
|3   4|
```

If you feel you need to be fancier, you can use graphics characters.

```
┌     ┐
│1   2│
│3   4│
└     ┘
```