# How can I typeset a crossword puzzle using Stack Exchange markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

I'm wondering if it's possible to typeset crossword puzzles using Stack Exchange markdown.  I'm after something like this:

> [image]
>
> <sub>[Love-ins? A capital idea for a cryptic crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100079/love-ins-a-capital-idea-for-a-cryptic-crossword)</sub>

However, I want it to be editable: answerers can copy/paste the code from the question, and edit in the solution---no image fiddling.  (I'm interested since crosswords [arose at Chinese.SE](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/is-idiom-puzzle-game-on-topic).)

**Question**: How can I typeset a crossword puzzle using Stack Exchange markdown?

I feel like there should be some reasonable way to do this using Unicode or <kbd>kbd</kbd> trickery.  An attempt:

> ```
> ⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
> ⬛①⬜②⬛③⬜④⬜⑤⬜⬛⑥⑦⬜⑧⬛  
> ⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⑨⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛  
> ⬛⑩⬜⬜⬜⬜⬛⑪⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬛  
> ⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛  
> ⬛⬛⑫⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬛⑬⬜⬜⬜⑭⬛  
> ⬛⑮⬛⬜⬛⬛⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬛⬛⬜⬛  
> ⬛⑯⬜⬜⬜⑰⬜⬜⬛⑱⬜⬜⬜⑲⬜⬜⬛  
> ⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛  
> ⬛㉑⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜㉒⬛㉓⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬛  
> ⬛⬜⬛⬛⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬛⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛  
> ⬛㉔⬜㉕⬜⬜⬛㉖⬜⬜⬜㉗⬜⬜⬜⬛⬛  
> ⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛㉘⬛  
> ⬛㉙⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬛㉚⬜⬜⬜⬜⬛  
> ⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛⬜⬛  
> ⬛㉛⬜⬜⬜⬛㉜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬛㉝⬜⬜⬛  
> ⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
> ```

filled in in Chinese:

> ```
> ⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛  
> ⬛索月研⬛属一紙次記理⬛同振発毎⬛  
> ⬛獲⬛対⬛更⬛由⬛家⬛図⬛理⬛半⬛  
> ⬛携伊共込社⬛問獲写子子学土保改⬛  
> ⬛獲⬛写⬛子⬛子⬛学⬛土⬛保⬛改⬛  
> ⬛⬛鎖掲具夏申振病事⬛故景刊陽投⬛  
> ⬛洋⬛因⬛⬛⬛唆⬛活⬛読⬛⬛⬛緑⬛  
> ⬛裏時導弁発携東⬛行付投術築州向⬛  
> ⬛賞⬛騒⬛耳⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛転⬛堀⬛読⬛  
> ⬛順曜急供言残見⬛般広挙條題凶紙⬛  
> ⬛止⬛⬛⬛境⬛張⬛写⬛⬛⬛融⬛盗⬛  
> ⬛売野奏由手⬛無前品家件水掲墓⬛⬛  
> ⬛液⬛申⬛問⬛康⬛料⬛史⬛軽⬛今⬛  
> ⬛覧出旬会部覧麻生職⬛砦稿小本率⬛  
> ⬛写⬛暮⬛掲⬛検⬛名⬛空⬛本⬛潟⬛  
> ⬛術発光日⬛表雲詐設結紙⬛再融講⬛  
> ⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
> ```

This doesn't display well on my phone.  But maybe if we stick to full-width characters:

> ```
> ．．．．．．．．．．．．．．     ．．．．．．．．．．．．．．  
> ．．①＃＃②．．．．．．．．     ．．馬前覆水．．．．．．．．  
> ．．．．．＃．．．③＃＃＃．     ．．．．．到．．．夜夜笙歌．  
> ．．．．．＃④．．．＃．．．     ．．．．．成背．．．涼．．．  
> ．．．⑤＃＃＃．．．＃．．．     ．．．眾志成城．．．如．．．  
> ．．．．＃．＃．．⑥＃＃⑦．     ．．．．同．借．．萬水千山．  
> ．⑧．．＃．⑨＃＃＃．．＃．     ．驚．．道．一鳴驚人．．窮．  
> ．⑩＃＃＃．．．．＃．．＃．     ．天作之合．．．．空．．水．  
> ．＃．．．．⑪＃＃＃．．＃．     ．動．．．．花街柳巷．．盡．  
> ．＃．⑫＃＃＃．．．．．．．     ．地．明日黃花．．．．．．．  
> ．．．．．．⑬＃＃＃．．．．     ．．．．．．世態炎涼．．．．  
> ．．．⑭＃＃＃．．．．．⑮．     ．．．楚河漢界．．．．．嵗．  
> ．．．＃．．．．⑯＃＃＃＃．     ．．．楚．．．．高處不勝寒．  
> ．．．＃．．．．．＃．．＃．     ．．．可．．．．．變．．三．  
> ．．．⑰＃＃⑱．．＃．．＃．     ．．．憐香惜玉．．不．．友．  
> ．．．．．．⑲＃＃＃．．．．     ．．．．．．石破天驚．．．．  
> ．．．．⑳＃＃＃．．．．．．     ．．．．萬念俱灰．．．．．．  
> ．．．．．．＃．．．．．．．     ．．．．．．焚．．．．．．．  
> ．．．．．．．．．．．．．．     ．．．．．．．．．．．．．．
> ```

Comment: I don't think people bother, on puzzling where this often happens, crosswords [seem to be uploaded as png](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92269/28599)

Comment: you would need to find glyphs that all have the same width or can be made same width by adding `&nbsp;`. But that still relies on the local installed font to be the same across all systems. One option I don 't have time for now to experiment with is creating small images for the black and white block and images for each number. That allows you still to build any grid but it does rely an images to control width and height. Not pure markdown.

Comment: This would require special coding like the matches on https://chess.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

```
–––––––––––––––––
|1  |   |2  |XXX|
|   |   |   |XXX|
–––––––––––––––––
|   |XXX|   |XXX|
|   |XXX|   |XXX|
–––––––––––––––––
|10 |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |
–––––––––––––––––
```

Does it look pretty? No. Will it be easy to fill in? Not really. But we never got [support for tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/295232) which has a much wider use case than this. (This feature did get mentioned again at the end of the [CommonMark migration post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/295232), and @rene spotted a [relevant recent Tweet](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1291692938284732417), so who knows?)

Also, some sites support MathJax, and you can create [nice looking tables](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42124/11110). I'm sure somebody is able to create a decent looking crossword, but again it will not be too easy to fill it in.

Comment: Well, it takes 6 to 8 weeks to name [the feature flag](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1291692938284732417) then another 6 to 8 to build the frigging feature ...