# Stack overflow needs moar bling

Tags: support, design

I like voting and I like bling! How can I get some bling in my voting???

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/stack-overflows-voting-system-is-not-entertaining-enough

Comment: moar sauce bump

Comment: @mmyers possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35052/should-stackoverflow-com-have-rounded-corners/35059#35059

Answer (score 2):

Yo dawg, I herd you like bling so I put some bling in ur voting so u can bling while you bling.

```
.vote-up-off,
.vote-up-on,
.vote-down-off,
.vote-down-on,
.comment-up-on,
.comment-up-off,
.star-on,
.star-off,
.vote-accepted-off,
.vote-accepted-on,
.comment-hover .comment-score {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.comment-up-off,
.vote-up-off,
.vote-down-off,
.star-off,
.vote-accepted-off {
  opacity: .3;
}

.comment-up-on,
.vote-up-on,
.vote-down-on,
.star-on,
.vote-accepted-on {
  opacity: .6;
}

.comment-hover .comment-score {
  text-shadow: hsl(0,0%,80%) -1px 1px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -2px 2px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -3px 3px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -4px 4px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -5px 5px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -6px 6px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -7px 7px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -8px 8px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -9px 9px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -10px 10px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -11px 11px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -12px 12px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -13px 13px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -14px 14px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -15px 15px, hsl(0,0%,80%) -16px 16px;
}

.star-on {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg); //SUPER BLING
}

.vote-accepted-on {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px green;
}

.comment-up-on:hover,
.comment-up-off:hover,
.vote-up-off:hover,
.vote-up-on:hover,
.vote-down-off:hover,
.vote-down-on:hover,
.star-on:hover,
.star-off:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

#### [SLOW MOTION SUPER BLING ACTION](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Superbling.ogv)

Comment: want on meta dood!

Comment: Fo sho. (You are quite possibly "keeping it real", as I believe the young people say.) :-)

Comment: Not nuff bling? I herd you like wiki so...

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaah shiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii